# Javascript angular chain of promises in for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I would like that the for loop will be executed and then the result will be sent over the next function:

```
FindIdsRequests =  function(){
    results = $scope.requests
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    var array = []
    for (var i in results) {
        promise = promise.then(function(){
            array.push(results[i].uid)      
        })
        return promise
    }
    return promise.then(function(){
        return array
    })
}

$scope.ConfirmRequests = function(){
    //alert('req'+JSON.stringify($scope.requests))
    FindIdsRequests().then(function(array){
        alert('arr'+JSON.stringify(array))
    })
})
```

the FindIdsRequests function should return the result of the for loop however there is no return (the alert is not printed so does not arrive there). Any idea?

Comment: You don't need a promise here... everything you are showing is synchronous. Just return the array

Comment: It fails because you dont actually call the FindIdsRequests  function.

Comment: sorry I forgot the brakets () but still the function FindIdsRequests does not return.

Comment: @ai20 nothing ever resolves the promise

Comment: What exactly is your use case? There are a lot of problems here first of which is you haven't shown a real reason to need promises

Comment: well it's complicated to explain in few words at it involves what can be in the $scope.requests array which may be empty or undefined even. Anyway can you be so kingd to make this code work?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantages of `$q` insted of returning a promise like so:

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2]);
```

For example:

```
FindIdsRequests =  function(){

    var requests = $scope.requests;
    var results = [];    
    var array = [];

    for (var i in requests) {

        var req = $http.get('http://someUrl.com/' + requests[i].uid);

        array.push(req);

        req.then(function (response) {
            results.push(response.data);
        });
    }

    return $q.all(array).then(function(){
        return results;
    });
}
```

This code will return a promisse of all promisses in the array to  be resolved.

Comment: `$q.all` resolves if and only if all promises in the array are resolved. So then, if any of the promises fail to resolve, $q.all also fails.

Comment: this won't work ... final `return` will never be reached and array is not an array of promises and nothing resolves `promise` so array will always be empty

Comment: yes it doesn't work @charlietfl can you please write a solution? thanks

Comment: It doesn't work because you are asking for people to produce a solution for a code that doesn't evem make sense. Sorry but, I simply can't guess what your code is suposed to do. So I've updated my answer with a proper example of how using `$q.all` can solve your problem. But write it up is up to you mate, good luky.

Comment: new answer is better but you don't need `var deferred = $q.defer();` ... just return `$q.all` ... the extra promise is an anti-pattern

Comment: Well I think I need a promise to do that. The method must return a promise that resolves an array of results. `$q.all` doesn's serve for that purpose. I mean, it could be in a different situation where a result wouldn't make difference, but in this case I have to produce a result that is an array. Don't you think?

Comment: since you are using `$http` successful requests will resolve each promise in array of promises , and returning `$q.all(array)` would resolve after all requests resolve. So just doing `return $q.all(arr).then(function(){ return results;})` would pass the results to next `then`

Comment: Oh sure! I understand what you saying now. Well, you can update the answer and participate if you like. Will you?

Comment: you should be able to handle that

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

1. You are overwriting `promise` in each iteration of loop... so there is only ever one `promise`
2. There is no resolve of promise to ever trigger `then()` so the array will always be empty
3. You have a `return` in the loop so the loop will break on first iteration and never complete
4. If this were asynchronous `i` will not be what you think it is inside `then()` as it will have reached it's end before the promise resolves

I see no need to write this up in code since everything you are doing is synchronous and shows no need for promise in the first place

Comment: for point 4: do you think that if I define the variable before then will be fine? look at  my answer.

Comment: No you need a closure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks also to the comments of @charlietlf the following code works:

```
FindIdsRequests =  function(){

    results = $scope.requests
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    var array = []
    for (var i in results) {
        alert('www'+JSON.stringify(results[i].uid))
        var obj = results[i].uid
        promise = promise.then(function(){
            array.push(results[i].uid)      
        })
        //return promise
    }
    deferred.resolve(array)
    return promise.then(function(){
            alert('ee'+JSON.stringify(array))
            return array
     })
}
```

essentially I forgot to put the resolve.

Comment: this code still makes no sense... nothing resolves `promise` so the `then()` won't ever run

Comment: as far as I understand is resolved in the deferred object. At least it works although I understand what you mean

Comment: if it's working in your real code something is very different there then

Comment: no it's working now. Why do you think it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a Chain of Promises from an Array of Promises

Use `$.when` to create an empty promise and use a `for` loop to create a chain:

```
function chainPromiseArray(promiseArray){
    var promise = $q.when();
    var array = [];
    for (var i=0;  i < promiseArray.length; i++) {
        promise = promise.then(function(){
            var derivedPromise = promiseArray[i].then(function(result) {
                //push data
                array.push(result.data);
            });
            //return promise to chain
            return derivedPromise;
        });
    };
    var finalPromise =  promise.then(function(){
        return array;
    });
    return finalPromise;
};
```

The above example starts with an empty promise, then chains from that empty promise. The final promise will resolve to the array created by the chain.

> ### Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> --[AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

The example executes the promises sequentially. To execute the promises in parallel use the [$q.all method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Comment: This is all fine and dandy except the OP's `FindIdsRequests()` function has no async components and thus can just be a regular function and does not need promises at all.  Using promises is just complicating something that can be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FindIdsRequests()` function has no async elements in the code as shown so it can just be a synchronous function and, in fact, trying to use promises in it is just complicating a very simple operation:

```
// get an array of uid from $scope.requests
function FindIdsRequests() {
    return $scope.requests.map(function(item) {
        return item.uid;
    });
});

$scope.ConfirmRequests = function() {
    var ids = FindIdsRequests();
    console.log('arr: '+ JSON.stringify(ids));
})
```